# Is it possible to create a perma link to a page in an online PDF file?

Tags: internet, pdf, web, adobe-acrobat

I have a link to a PDF file online.

I want to expand the link so it navigates to the desired page in the document.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes, it is](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/317/317300.html).

Append `#page=123` to the end of you link.